# How do you use variables in regex?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, yaml

I am trying to pull from this string the photo ID : `30280` :

```
"--- !ruby/struct:PhotoJob \nimage_id: 30280\n"
```

I've seen this sort of thing done in regex before where you can look for a couple parameters that match like `/nimage_id: \d/` and then return `\d`.

How can I return `/d` or the number `30280` from that string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use group matches `"--- !ruby/struct:PhotoJob \nimage_id: 30280\n".scan(/image_id: (\d+)/)[0]`

```
>> matches = "--- !ruby/struct:PhotoJob \nimage_id: 30280\n".match(/struct:(.*) .*image_id: (\d+)/m)
=> #<MatchData "struct:PhotoJob \nimage_id: 30280" 1:"PhotoJob" 2:"30280">
>> matches[1]
=> "PhotoJob"
>> matches[2]
=> "30280"
```

Comment: sure missed this, 1 is when using match

Comment: Thank mpapis! Now I achieved level 3 programmer status.

Answer (score 5):

What's funny is that you have a Ruby Struct there, so you could do the following and let YAML take care of the parsing.

```
PhotoJob = Struct.new(:image_id)
job = YAML.load("--- !ruby/struct:PhotoJob \nimage_id: 30280\n")
job.image_id
=> 30280
```

Comment: Wow super beast of an answer. Thanks so much!

Comment: +1. I saw it was YAML right away. Good job on nailing the correct way to handle the data.

Answer (score 1):

```
str = "--- !ruby/struct:PhotoJob \nimage_id: 30280\n"
image_id = str.scan(/\d+/)[0]
#=> "30280"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
RE = '\nimage_id: (\d+)\n'
```

The group defined by parentheses around \d+ catches the number